# ios function detect when returns from other app

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app with a cover video and a facebook login. When you push facebook login, my app opens safari or facebook app and then returns again to my app.

When it returns, my video is paused and I what I need is to know which ios function I have to write to play it again.

Thanks!

Comment: it really depends if you want to save the state (you should take a look in the app lifecycle) to restore it later or not. In the app delegate you control when "the app" has changed of state internally and the iOS task manager allows you to save some state there. Try to take a look in your view controller to save the current state of your video player. You can do that in the app delegate using notifications as well, but I would recommend you to leave the app delegate with no modifications; modify it in the case you want to modify the state of the app but not a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for UIApplicatoinDelegate's [applicationDidBecomeActive:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive:) do detect when your app gets active. But if you are using the Facebook SDK I think there is a callback for this also.